# Pass MySQLDB connection to SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mysql-python

If I create a connection that works to `MySQL` using MySQLdb like this:

```
connection = MySQLdb.connect(
        host= os.getenv("HOST"),
        user=os.getenv("USERNAME"),
        passwd= os.getenv("PASSWORD"),
        db= os.getenv("DATABASE"),
        ssl_mode = "VERIFY_IDENTITY",
        ssl      = {
            "ca": "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
        }
    )
```

Is there a way to pass this connection to `SQLAlchemy` `create_engine` so I **don't** have to do the string thing?

```
engine = create_engine("mysql+:MySQLdb//"...")
```

Comment: Why would you want that? Sqlalchemy maintains a connection pool (i.e. multiple connections, as needed), so giving it one connection would degrade its functionality.

Comment: I see. Thanks looks like I need to connect the create_engine way